# Is manhood defined in the Bible?

Tags: bible, life-of-jesus, scriptures

I have recently started reasearching the differences and similarites between religion's and their definitions of manhood. I was very interested to find that this question had not been previously asked when I search manhood:

**How should a man should conduct himself in modern society, according to scriptures in the Holy Bible?**

Comment: I've upvoted, but also VtC. Here is why: there is no "prooftext" to go to for such a definition; various Christian traditions (and even just individual churches, authors, or theologians) will have different *details*, or even full interpretations of this question; compiling all of the positive and negative examples of manhood (or any other "hood") are book-creating efforts, not really something that can be answered as a cohesive, coherent answer in an SE format. That said, if this were narrowed akin to, "How does <denomination> define manhood according to the Bible," it'd be fantastic!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is still too broad after the current edit.

Answer (score 1):

> And to Adam he said, "...cursed is the ground because of you; in pain you shall eat of it all the days of your life; (Genesis 3:17) - Men are primarily responsible for working the earth for food.

> ...until we all attain to the unity of the faith and of the knowledge of the Son of God, to mature manhood, to the measure of the stature of the fullness of Christ, so that we may no longer be children, tossed to and fro by the waves and carried about by every wind of doctrine, by human cunning, by craftiness in deceitful schemes. (Ephesians 4:13, 14)

- Men are not confused by every new religion or philosophy that comes around, but know Jesus are united with others who know him.

> Husbands, love your wives, as Christ loved the church and gave himself up for her... (Ephesians 5:25)

- If a man is married, he should sacrifice his selfishness in the way he loves his wife.

> I want you to be free from anxieties. The unmarried man is anxious about the things of the Lord, how to please the Lord. (1 Corinthians 7:32)

- If a man is un-married, his commitment should be to pleasing the Lord.

> Fathers, do not provoke your children to anger, but bring them up in the discipline and instruction of the Lord. (Ephesians 6:4)

- If a man has children, he is primarily responsible for instructing them in God's ways and correcting them when they go astray.

Comment: Welcome to C.SE! When you get the chance, please check out our [about] and specifically [How we are different than other sites](http://tinyurl.com/csedifferent). I see that these are verses about men, but I don't think that this actually answers what "manhood" is supposed to be.

Answer (score 1):

Men's minister [Edwin Louis Cole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Louis_Cole) used to say, "Manhood and Christlikeness are synonymous." His point was that Jesus is our example in all things, including manhood.

I'm not saying that the picture of Jesus we have from the Bible tells us *everything* about manhood, but rather that it gives us more insight into what manhood is really all about than any thing or anyone else. There are, of course, other great examples of manhood in the Bible - Abraham, Moses, David and other heroes of the faith - but none of them gets close to the perfection we see in Christ.

One of the difficulties with this view is that Jesus circumstances vary from ours in all sorts of different ways - he didn't marry or have a family for example. However, the principles that he taught (both through instruction and example) apply to all our situations. For example, his actions towards his disciples illustrate the kinds of behaviour he expects us to show our children. His directive to love others as ourself applies to our relationship with our wives.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your answer. But I would like to raise the question of how a man could learn how to deal in matter of raising a family from Jesus, since he didn't marry or have children?

Comment: Good question - I've expanded my answer.